# how to use lapack under windows

Tags: c++, windows, fortran, lapack, lapack++

I want to use lapack and make C++ matrix wrapper for it, but lapack is written in Fortran, there are some clapack but I want to use it from source. compile firstly *.f and *.cpp files to object files then link it into a application..

the following apps and sources that I have.

- visual studio proff edition,dev c++,ultimate++,mingw whatever
- g95 and gfortran (under mingw) compiler
- lapack (latest source)
- blas (included in lapack)

How can I make an application please help...

My Operating System is Windows 7 and CPU Core2Duo and I dont have Intel math kernel

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [official C bindings for LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/#_standard_c_language_apis_for_lapack), and then build your C++ wrapper around that. That avoids the issue of having to worry about the Fortran calling conventions, and the C bindings are a bit friendlier for C/C++ programmers than calling the Fortran routines directly.

Additionally, you could use one of the C++ matrix libraries that are already available, instead of rolling your own. I recommend [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

PS.: Eigen matrices/vectors have a data() member that allows calling LAPACK without having to make temporary copies.

Comment: You can also try [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net), which is an efficient C++ wrapper for LAPACK (and BLAS). Like Eigen, it also uses expression templates for speed.  However, Armadillo differs from Eigen in that its syntax (API) closely resembles Matlab.